# Fade Out And fade in Div with specific class and id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a little issue with some jquery code. I have some divs (look bellow)

```
<div class="add" id="1">Follow</div>
<div class="added" id="1">Following</div>

<div class="add" id="2">Follow</div>
<div class="added" id="2">Following</div>
```

I am trying when user clicks in each div with class add to fadeout the specific div and fade in the next div with class added.

Check my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){

$('.add').click(function () {
$(this).find('.add').hide("fast");
$(this).find('.added').fadeIn("slow");
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: **Note:** IDs must be unique

Comment: And **Note**: IDs shouldn't start with a number

Comment: @A.Wolff - In HTML5 it's OK.

Comment: Starting with HTML5, IDs starting with numbers are just fine

Comment: @j08691 ya but it's not in CSS. BTW, i used the word "shouldn't" ;)

Comment: @devnull69 i wouldn't say "IDs starting with numbers are just fine". It will be find once CSS will handle it too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ID's` must be unique and it should not be a `number`. You have to set different `ids` for your `divs`. Additionally you have to hide the div with class `.added` initially to achieve your need.

Because `fadeIn` wont work on elements which are already visible.

Try,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
   $('.added').hide();
   $('.add').click(function () {
       $(this).hide("fast");
       $(this).next('.added').fadeIn("slow");
    }); 
 });
</script>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/eAgb5/)

Comment: The Hide is Working but it doesnt fadeIn the .added div!

Comment: @IreneT. Now see the code. I thought you might have tried out the demo. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this)` to hide current element and use next to hide `.added`, also use unique ids to make your html valid.

The next element is already visible you probably need `fadeOut()` to hide it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B33yA/)**

```
$('.add').click(function () {
   $(this).hide("fast");
   $(this).next('.added').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have same id on multiple elements. Instead use a class

```
 $('.add').on('click', function(){ $(this).fadeOut().next('.added').fadeIn(); });
```

Comment: True, but the code doesn't use ids so they can't be the problem.

Comment: True, but let's write valid html

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1. Ids should be unique. In case, you need same selector on group of elements, use `class`.
2. `this` reference contains the target on which event listener is added, So your `this` context contains the element with `add` class. `jquery.find()` tries to match the selector on the children. That's why your code is not working.

Just try this <kbd>[Jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/AwIvimi/1/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="add" id="1">Follow</div>
  <div class="added" id="1">Following</div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$('.wrapper').click(function () {
  $(this).find('.add').hide("fast");
  $(this).find('.added').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Idea: Bind event listener on parent.